# ASP.NET Route not being hit with correct mapping

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, html-helper, t4mvc

Why is:

```
@Url.Action("Divisions", "Widgets", new {version = 1, eventId = Model.Event.Id, slug = Model.Event.Slug})
```

Generating this:

```
http://localhost:2227/widgets/divisions?version=1&eventid=36295&slug=notifications
```

When my route is like this.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                "DefaultWidget",
                "widgets/v{version}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Widgets", action = "NotFound", version = 1, slug = "event"},
                new { version = @"\d+" }
                );
```

and action is like this in the WidgetsController

```
 public virtual ActionResult Divisions(int version, int? eventId, string slug)
        {
            return GetDivisions(eventId, new WidgetEventViewModel(version));
        }
```

The route should look like this:

```
http://localhost:2227/widgets/v1/divisions?eventid=36295
```

Comment: You `@Url.Action()` does not match that route. What are you expecting the url to look like?

Comment: I guess that would of been smart to add, `http://localhost:2227/widgets/v1/divisions?eventid=36295`

Comment: You have also shown `ActionResult Event()` (did you mean `ActionResult divisions()`? And did you want both `eventid` and `slug` to be query strings (`/widgets/v1/divisions?eventid=36295&slug=MySlug`) or `/widgets/v1/divisions/36295/MySlug`

Comment: Yes wrong copy and paste content

Comment: If I remove slug = "event" from the route it works correctly.  Not sure why.

Comment: Remove `slug = "event"` in the route definition (or change the route to `widgets/v{version}/{action}/{eventid}/{slug}`

Comment: Done, if you make that the answer ill update it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `slug = "event"` from the route definition (you do not have a placeholder in the `url` so the route is not matched)

Alternatively change the url parameter to

```
"widgets/v{version}/{action}/{eventid}/{slug}",
```

which would generate (assuming version = 1, eventid = 36295 and slug = "MySlug")

```
/widgets/v1/divisions/36295/MySlug
```